# Apply Class to capture<? extends class>

Tags: java

I have an Interface in a library, that looks like this:

```
public interface Sender<T> {

  String send(T parameters);
}
```

It's a library, so I prefer a solution without changing this.
Now, there are several classes that implement this interface. Each class Implements it in a way that T extends a Class ParamsVal.

Now, I'ld like to implement a queue where I can save the data that fit the parameter and call send() in a decided time (I need the return value String, therefore I can't simply use a Runnable and a thread).

So, I created a class like this:

```
public class MessageEntry{
  private ParamsVal messageParameters;
  private Sender<? extends ParamsVal> sender;


  public MessageEntry(ParamsVal messageParameters, Sender<? extends ParamsVal> sender) {
      this.messageParameters = messageParameters;
      this.sender = sender;
  }

  public String send(){
      return this.sender.send(this.messageParameters);
  }
}
```

With the return-Line of send() I get the error

```
 send(capture<? extends ParamsVal>) in Sender cannot be applied to (ParamsVal)
```

Any ideas, how to solve this?

Edit: Fixed minor copycodeerror

Comment: `Sender<? extends ParamsVal> sender` -> `Sender<ParamsVal> sender`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and usually best way to resolve generic wildcard issues when you don't understand them, is to remove the wildcard.

So, as others suggested, use `Sender<ParamsVal> sender` instead.

Now, as for what is happening and what you could have done instead if you wish to be the most flexible possible.

`Sender<ParamsVal>` means "A Sender that sends ParamsVal objects".

`Sender<? extends ParamsVal>` means "A Sender. I don't know what it sends. But I do know that whatever it sends, that things is a subtype of ParamsVal, or possibly ParamsVal itself".

We don't know what it can send, so we can't ask it to send ParamsVal objects. That might not be the kinds of objects it can send. We do know that the kind of objects it can send, extends that. But this is not useful information.

Instead you want `Sender<? super ParamsVal>`. It means "A Sender. I don't know what it sends. But I do know that whatever it sends, that things is a supertype of ParamsVal, or possibly ParamsVal itself".

Since whatever the sender can send is a supertype of ParamsVal, we do know that in any case it can send a ParamsVal.